# php variables concatenation

Tags: php, variables, concatenation

suppose we have these variables

```
$x = 'some string';
$y = 'another string';
```

and we need to concatenate another string to both of them
how can we do that in one line instead of two line

for example we can concatenate them like that

```
$x .= ' concatenated string';
$y .= ' concatenated string';
```

I need to do this in one line so can any one help me in this 
thanks in advance

Comment: Get rid of the line break after the `;`.

Comment: Would you mind explaining why you need to do it in one line? Something wrong with your enter key?

Comment: @Barmar this is not what he meant. He wanted to get rid of the doubled `' concatenated string'`, I think.

Comment: If you mean one statement, I don't think there's a way to do that.

Comment: `list($x,$y) = array($x . ' concatenated string', $y . ' concatenated string');`. Not a real improvement though...

Answer (score 1):

If an array is ok for you instead of scalars, you can use one statement in a loop, but this only makes sense if you do it for more than just two strings:

```php
$strings=array(
  "a" => "some string",
  "b" => "another string");

foreach ($strings as $key=>$value) {
        $strings[$key] = $value." concatenated string";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list($x,$y)=array($x.$add,$y.$add);
```

That's one possible way.

```
$x = 'some string';
$y = 'another string';
$c="concatenated string";
list($x,$y)=array($x.$c,$y.$c);
```

**[Fiddle](https://eval.in/315545)**

Then theres another fun way

```
$y=($x=$x.$c)? $y.$c : $y;
```

**[Fiddle](https://eval.in/315550)**

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean this ?

```
$c = 'concatenated string';
$x .= $c;
$y .= $c;
```